# After upgrade app to 64-bit Apk anaylzer only hows 32-bit in lib

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, 64-bit

I am struggeling to upgrade my app to support 64 bit.
I have added

`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

in build.gradle, but when I analyze the apk I only see 32 bit in lib
[image: APK Analyzer]

I have quite a lot of external stuff imported in dependencies, so I guess at last one of them is not 64-bit compliant.
The developer guide doesn't mention anything about how to find out which one is causing problems. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope you are referring to https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit. Your native component is built using CMake or ndk-build?   https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#build_arguments

Comment: With try&error, I found out now which component was offending: with implementation 'com.sumup:merchant-sdk:3.2.0' apk analyzer is happy.
With implementation 'com.sumup:merchant-sdk:3.1.2' it is not. Strange thing is that AS didnt mark this one as having a newer version available, something it always does.

Comment: It will be great for opensource if you can put the steps you followed as part of trial & error to identify the non-64-bit native component.

Comment: Well, I created a new dummy empty project and added each 'implementation' one by one. Each time I generated an APK and did an APK Analyze until the lib folder showed that 64 bit was missing. VERY cumbersome and boring, but successful.